# dataframe.idxmax() - first N occurences

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas `dataframe.idxmax()` function returns the index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.

**Is there a way to instead return the index of top N number of occurrences?**

The line in question:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(['columnA', 'columnB'], sort=False)['columnC'].idxmax()]
```

I want this to return the top N number of indices based on the Nth largest values in `df['columnC']`. So if `df['columnC']` contains values 5, 10, 20, 50, 75, 90, 100 and `N=3`, I want the indices of rows with values of 75, 90, and 100.

**Edit:**

DataFrame looks something like this:

```
raw_data = {'cities': ['LA', 'LA', 'LA', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Chicago', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston', 'Boston'], 
        'location': ['pub', 'dive', 'club', 'disco', 'cinema', 'cafe', 'diner', 'bowling','supermarket', 'pizza', 'icecream', 'music'], 
        'distance': ['0', '50', '100', '5', '75', '300', '20', '40', '70', '400', '2000', '2'], 
        'score': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['cities', 'location', 'distance', 'score'])
df
```

Comment: you can always loop, keep the a list of the N df returned and concat them

Comment: You want to return the top `N` indices of the maximum value? What happens if N is 3, but the maximum value is only repeated twice? Do we return the next highest number in the third index, or do we only return 2 values?

Comment: Will rephrase. I mean the highest value, second highest value...N highest value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `nlargest`. Here is an exemple

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'t' : [0, 8,32, 56, 96, 128],
               'T2' : [333, 500, 333, 500, 333, 460],
              })
df['t'].nlargest(3).index.tolist()

Out [1]:
[5, 4, 3]
```

So this is what you are looking for :

```py
N = 3
df2 = df.loc[df.groupby(['columnA', 'columnB'], sort=False)['columnC'].nlargest(N).index.tolist()]
```

Comment: I tried this on my df and it returns: KeyError: u"None of [Index(['columnA' )] are in the [index]

Comment: Not normal, can you edit your question with your dataframe, or a sample of it ?

Answer (score 2):

With specific custom function:

```
In [197]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,5,2,1,0,5,4,5,1,3,5,1,5]})                                          

In [198]: def top_max_idx(df, col, n): 
     ...:     return df[col][df[col] == df[col].max()].index[:n].tolist() 
     ...:                                                                                                       

In [199]: top_max_idx(df, 'col', 3)                                                                             
Out[199]: [3, 7, 9]
```